# How to send requests to bittorrent tracker using python requests

Tags: python-requests, bittorrent, hashlib, tracker, libtorrent

I was studying the bittorrent protocol, and wanted to try out some tracker requests to get info about peers and stuff, but I am unable to receive any proper response from any of the tracker I've tried

These are what my params look like

```py
{'info_hash': '7bf74c4fd609bf288523f7cd51af3bdbc19df610', 'peer_id': '139a3f2ff0143c9f24c19c4f95ed1378aaf449d2', 'port': '6881', 'uploaded': '0', 'downloaded': '0', 'left': '931135488', 'compact': '1', 'no_peer_id': '0', 'event': 'started'}
```

```py
import bencoding
import hashlib
import secrets
import requests
import urllib

file = open('../altlinux.torrent', 'rb')
data = bencoding.bdecode(file.read())
info_hash = hashlib.sha1(bencoding.bencode(data[b'info'])).hexdigest()
params = {
    'info_hash': info_hash,
    'peer_id': secrets.token_hex(20),
    'port': '6881',
    'uploaded': '0',
    'downloaded': '0',
    'left': str(data[b'info'][b'length']),
    'compact': '1',
    'no_peer_id': '0',
    'event': 'started'
}
print(params)
page = requests.get(data[b'announce'], params=params)
print(page.text
```

So this is what I wrote, and I'm getting the same error,

```py
d14:failure reason50:Torrent is not authorized for use on this tracker.e
```

I've even tried encoding info_hash to

```py
urllib.parse.quote_plus(info_hash)
```

just to make it url encoded format insted of hexdigest

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong
Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the raw `info_hash`, not an encoded version of it.  The same is true of the `peer_id` as well:

```py
params = {
    'info_hash': bytes.fromhex(info_hash),
    'peer_id': bytes.fromhex(secrets.token_hex(20)),
    'port': '6881',
    'uploaded': '0',
    'downloaded': '0',
    'left': str(data[b'info'][b'length']),
    'compact': '1',
    'no_peer_id': '0',
    'event': 'started'
}
```

Also, it should be pointed out that this will only work for single file torrents.  The way you're getting the length will need to handle the `files` element in torrents when you see one with multiple files, since those don't have a `length` entry.

Answer (score 0):

`info_hash` is not supposed to be the *hex* representation. It's supposed to be the *binary* representation. i.e. you need to URL encode it. i.e. don't call `.hexdigest()`.

It looks like when you call `urllib.parse.quote_plus(info_hash)` you're URL encoding the hex representation of the info hash. i.e. it's still hex encoded.

You probably want to use something like `urllib.parse.quote(info_hash)`